# Connecting Docker Sqlite container to Java

Tags: java, docker, sqlite

I just can't find the correct information on the web.

I plan to run sqlite with Docker so that the information can be persisted to a local volume. My Dockerfile is

```
FROM alpine:3.14
RUN apk add --update sqlite
RUN mkdir /db
WORKDIR /db
ENTRYPOINT ["sqlite3"]
CMD ["mydb.db"]

docker run -p 5000:5000 -v `passwd`:/db my-sqlite mydb.db
```

How do I mount this to a volume, so that data is persisted to the disk? Now I need the connection string - to connect from a Java project. What will this be ? I want to load up data from this db on starting the program, how would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You're having a big misconception about sqlite. Sqlite is an embedded database - that means it doesn't need a server to run but rather runs in the application.

Therefore you need to mount the `*.db` file into your application's container and use the JDBC driver of sqlite in order to use the database.

As far as I know, sqlite doesn't even support any sort of remote connection because that's not what it was made for.

Comment: How would the application talk to the db? Doesn't it need some kind of connection string?

Comment: Yes, it needs one. But instead of defining a server, you define a path where the application can find the *.db file.

Comment: So if I am using Docker, how would the path be specified?

Comment: I would also want to 'view' it, say through IntelliJ?

Comment: You'd mount the db file into your docker container. That's all you have to do.

Comment: Could you tell me the Docker code to mount it? The Java connection string? Sorry, I can't find anything on the internet about this, and my project depends on it.